# USB DVD drive suddenly has slower read speed?

Tags: windows, usb, dvd, ripping, imgburn

I have been using an LG GP65NB60 USB-DVD drive to rip some software installation DVDs to ISO using ImgBurn.

For a while, the drive was working normally. It is an 8x drive, meaning 3.3x at the smallest radius, and up to 8x at the end of the discs. Now, all of a sudden, it is running at half that speed, starting at 1.7x. ImgBurn is already configured to use the maximum read speed at that hasn't change. In the ImgBurn log, it still reports an 8x nominal read speed.

Why is the drive suddenly working at half speed?

Comment: Is this about the write speed of DVD+-R's? Are the dvd's all from the same identical package/batch/factory? Is the temp of the dvd writer still the same?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, I am talking strictly about reading discs.

Comment: Reading wasn't mentioned directly, but I suppose it could be deduced from  "to iso"... but the same questions apply, different DVD's might just read at different speeds, and temp or USB wires or plugs or dust in the drive / dirty discs can be temperamental too

Comment: this could maybe be some kind of copy protection scheme. i wonder if you could find accounts of similar behavior by searching around as if you are trying to rip a DVD - maybe thats a more common usecase